# Running script on multiple ubuntu computers automatically

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, shell

I have many ubuntu 10.04 computers.

Is there any program that can allow me to select a shell file, and have it automatically log in to each computer of a list of computers (through say ssh), and download and run the shell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
#!/bin/bash
myscript=`cat /dev/stdin`
echo "$myscript; exit;" | sshpass -p $3 ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $2@$1
```

You can then call the script like this:

```
cat script-to-run.sh | script-above.sh SERVER USERNAME PASSWORD
```

The script will run on the remote computer.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably write your own shell script to do so.  There is a great deal of info here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine.

Answer (score 0):

you might find python paramiko library useful. I wish you had provided more detailed spec. Here are some simple examples with the library.

http://jessenoller.com/2009/02/05/ssh-programming-with-paramiko-completely-different/